# Angular: How to append multiple form controls to form group

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using the latest version of Angular (v6.0.5).

I have a FormGroup consisting of 3 common controls and based on some logic i want to add other multiple controls to the same FormGroup.

I know i can use `this.form.addControl()` but i dont want to do this for each individual form control

Is there an easy way to do this?

Example:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    'id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'firstName' new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    'lastName' new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

if (blah) {
    // Append more FormControls here to same FormGroup
    this.form.addControl('houseNumber', new FormControl(''));
    this.form.addControl('street', new FormControl(''));
    this.form.addControl('postCode', new FormControl(''));
}
```

Comment: `['houseNumber', 'street', 'postCode'].forEach(x => this.form.addControl(x, new FormControl(''))`

Comment: @yurzui I can only add 1 control at a time, my question is, is there a way to add multiple at the same time?

Comment: With my code above you can add several controls

Comment: The only issue i have with this is i need to set the value to something different for each control other than `''`

Comment: You can have a map like `{ houseNumber: 'val1', street: 'val2...}`

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12747#issuecomment-259835873

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to delay the form creation you can simply do something like that:

```
// You can write this sugar, you don't have to write new FormControl
const form = {
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required]
};

if (blah) {
    form.someField: ['', Validators.required];
} else {
    form.someotherField: ['', Validators.required];
}

this.form = this.formBuilder.group(form);
```

Or this shorter inline version:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    ...(blah ? {form.someField: ['', Validators.required]} : {form.someotherField: ['', Validators.required]})
});
```

Answer (score 13):

For some reason Angular [didn't provide API](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12747#issuecomment-259835873) for that case.

You can simply loop over your controls and add it to FormGroup or you can build new FormGroup based on existing:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  'id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  'firstName': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  'lastName': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

let blah = true;

if (blah) {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...this.form.controls,
    'houseNumber': new FormControl(''),
    'street': new FormControl('')
  });
} else {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...this.form.controls,
    'otherControl': new FormControl(''),
    'otherControl2': new FormControl(''),
    'otherControl3': new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/DA9HDutDSde2WXwsMIix)**